# How do I get Windows entry to my GRUB Bootloader?

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

[image]The other day I deleted an EFI partition (for arch linux installation stuff) and created a new one. Then I had had numerous attempts to install GRUB on UEFI System using ARCH Linux Live USB, yet I succeeded. But Windows Entry on my GRUB is missing (which is quite obviously after EFI removal). Now am using Arch Linux and dunno how do I get windows entry to my grub back. I might try using Windows Live USB for restoring EFI, but I assume it would get rid of my grub entirely. Is there any workaround to do it the easy way?

Comment: You need the Windows boot files in the ESP. Grub uses those to boot Windows if Secure Boot is off. And then you can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. You may still have a UEFI boot entry, but it will refer by GUID to now missing partition. Run the full set of repairs from an UEFI booted Windows repair/recovery flash drive. Then grub2's os-prober should be able to find the Windows boot files. With UEFI, all systems share the ESP & have different folders. The only possible overwrite will be the fallback entry /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Both Windows & Linux write that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No installing Windows back to EFI should not destroy grub. In general you should not ever destroy an EFI partition only delete from it.

You might want to back up the contents of your EFI just in case Windows restore does something really stupid.  But certainly Windows bootloader and grub can and should be installed side by side in EFI.

Once installed your BIOS should give you the option to boot either Windows or grub.  So after you install, if your computer boots straight to Windows then check your BIOS settings.

Finally after you have both installed, go into Arch Linux and run `update-grub`.  This should then detect the Windows EFI entry and add Windows to your boot menu in grub